# How to grep by line/element that contains no characters

Tags: r, regex

I have a character vector with a number of elements.

```
(tmpsp <- c("Hi my name is Gary", "", "Welcome to my house", "", "    Do you like tea?"))

[1] "Hi my name is Gary"

[2] ""

[3] "Welcome to my house"

[4] ""

[5] "    Do you like tea?"
```

Some elements/lines of the vector are simply empty which I wish to remove.

I've attempted finding these lines with the following grep command

```
grep("^ ", tmpsp)
```

However it doesn't seem to work.

How can I grep elements that contain no characters?

For example, how would I find/remove elements [2] and [4]

Comment: If you really want to use regex for blank strings you could probably do `grep("^$", tmpsp)`, but you could just do `tmpsp == ""`.

Comment: so simple. thank you. could you explain the regex solution you've posted as i'm trying to learn

Comment: so simple. thank you. could you explain the regex solution you've posted as i'm trying to learn

Comment: `"^"` means the start of the string. `"$"` means the end of the string. `"^$"` means start of the string followed by end of the string with nothing in between.

Comment: `Filter(nzchar, tmpsp)` or `Filter(Negate(nzchar), tmpsp)` for the reverse

Comment: @rawr  You already had the solution in the comments.  You should have posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing if something is an empty string you don't need any fancy regex, just use `==`:

```
x = c("Hi", "", "Welcome", " Do")
x == ""
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```